# Failing to codesign "no such file or directory" on distribution

Tags: c#, xamarin

I've been stuck all day trying to get a Xamarin.iOS mobile application to distribute after archive.

The archive process runs smoothly, then when we attempt to distribute via Ad Hoc, it fails with a message complaining about a missing file.

The error is as follows:

```
Could not create ipa file for distribution of the archive '[redacted]'
/usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1
        
/usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1
        
Failed to codesign '.../Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/archives/Mobile.iOS 3-30-21 11.41 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Mobile.iOS.app//**/*.dylib': [redacted]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Mobile.iOS/17a75d5999f2d5c58a10f98135732a71be8d334fae491e1585d4d1f1bbfa6140/C:/Users/.../Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/archives/Mobile.iOS 3-30-21 11.41 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Mobile.iOS.app//**/*.dylib: No such file or directory

        
Failed to codesign '.../Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/archives/Mobile.iOS 3-30-21 11.41 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Mobile.iOS.app//**/*.metallib': [redacted]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Mobile.iOS/17a75d5999f2d5c58a10f98135732a71be8d334fae491e1585d4d1f1bbfa6140/C:/Users/.../Mobile.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/archives/Mobile.iOS 3-30-21 11.41 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Mobile.iOS.app//**/*.metallib: No such file or directory
```

I have shortened some file paths (...) and redacted some identifying information of our client.

To resolve this we have attempted to:

- The usual clean & rebuild
- Deleting /bin & /obj
- Clearing provisioning profiles & redownloading
- Deleting all build data/caches and the "iOS folder" from %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin
- Reinstalling visual studio
- Deleting & redownloading the project files (which work on other machines)

Any help/pointers would be appreciated

Comment: I noticed that you had deleted the cache manually . However , I suggest that you could delete them deeply by  running the following commands in Terminal on the Mac `rm –rf ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds
rm –rf ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA` .If the issue still exists , you could post the issue  to **Help Menu->Send Fedback->Report a problem** . The error log will be helpful if they would need to investigate possible causes.

Comment: Seems like similar problem reported here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/305682/xamarin-ios-app-distribute-failed-to-codesign.html
Work-around is to distribute from XCode on the Mac.

Comment: Warning. Don't delete the caches, this made the problem worse for me and now I'm in a pickle.